# pandas - Use datetime.time objects as a dtype

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, time-series

I am reading an Excel file that has the following structure:

```
    A               B 
2015-09-05       15:05:32
2015-09-05       19:05:02
```

I am reading this file using

```
df = pd.ExcelFile(filename).parse(..)
```

When I look at the `dtype`, of this DataFrame, I can see that the dates are parsed properly as `datetime64` objects, but the times are not:

```
>>> df.dtypes
     A         datetime64[ns]
     B         object
```

What's odd is that, when I look at the content of the `B`, I can see that they are all `datetime.time` objects

```
[s for s in main_df['B'].tolist() if type(s) is not datetime.time]
# There are no values that are *not* datetime.time objects
```

I'd like to convert this `B` column to something that I can use more readily. For instance, I'd like to use a `MultiIndex` with first the day, and then the time (so that I can group and aggregate). Or I'd like to join the two so that I have a single column that's the full date.

But at this point, I'm stuck. I tried converting them to `datetime`:

```
main_df['B'] = main_df['B'].astype('datetime64')
ValueError: Could not convert object to NumPy datetime
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to join the two, you could join them as strings:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'A' : ['2015-09-05', '2015-09-05'], 'B': ['15:05:32', '19:05:02']})
pd.to_datetime(df.A + ' ' + df.B)
```

Or you could use datetime to combine:

```
import datetime

df.apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.combine(x.A, x.B), axis=1)
```

Comment: This partially works when the dtypes are both object, but if one of the dtypes is `datetime64`, it gives an error. If you add this between the two lines, for instance: `df['A'] = df['A'].astype('datetime64')`

Comment: I guess you could specify its dtype as string when you read in, or use datetime as in edited answer.